# Phrases to describe advancement of Information Technology

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I would like to describe how fast information is exchanged with the convenience of information technology but can't think of a better way to phrase it with fewer words.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Transformation? There are quite a few good options. Try looking up Synonyms of both the words. [E.g. for evolution here](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/evolution). Flagging the post of [off topic.](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/466/policy-for-questions-that-are-entirely-answerable-with-a-dictionary)

Comment: @Bee Thanks but not synonyms of evolution or advancement

Comment: Please can you explain what you do mean then? This is how it reads.

Comment: Convenience or progress?   The Increasing convenience?  Frictionlessness?

Comment: @Bee I'm not looking for a single word to replace evolution/advancement. I think my original post is misleading. I've edited and hope it removes the confusion.

Comment: @whiskeychief Thanks. I've edited the original question and hope it clarifies.

Comment: Another question, is fast describing the information or the speed at which it is exchanged? I'm pretty certain you mean the latter

Comment: @Bee the speed at which it is exchanged. Thanks.

Comment: Bandwidth increases.  Friction decreases.  Speed increases.  The time required to transfer a given piece of data decreases.  Information sharing becomes faster, more transparent, more seamless.  Transfer speed increases.  The data rate increases.  The practicality increases.  The ease of sharing increases.  The difficulty decreases and the convenience increases.  The available bandwidth increases.   High-speed connections become more accessible and even faster.